# Getting UI Element from list view item template

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have ListView in my app that have style.

```
<ListView x:Name="FoldersListView"
          RightTapped="OnFoldersListViewRightTapped"                        
          Style="{StaticResource FoldersListViewStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel.Folders}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel.SelectedFolder, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And in xaml live tree I have loaded grids (DataTemplates for ItemTemplate) in ListView

[image]

How can I get each Grid from ListView in code behind?

```
foreach (var item in this.FoldersListView.Items)
{
    var recievedItem = this.FoldersListView.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=uwp+visual+tree+helper

Comment: I know about visual tree helper but if I try to get count of children in ListView im always getting 0 but items was loaded. I use string like this:

```var foldersCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this.FoldersListView);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get each Grid from ListView in code behind?

You will need to use the [VisualTreeHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621) to achieve this.

1. Get each ListViewItem by calling `ContainerFromItem` or `ContainerFromIndex` of the ListView
2. Create a recursive function to find DependencyObjects that are grid in side each ListViewItem.

Without knowing your real scenario about the item style, I just made a simple demo to show how it works. You could refer to the following code and change it a little bit for your scenario.

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <Grid >
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.Cs**

```
 public List<string> sourceList { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        sourceList = new List<string>();
        sourceList.Add("1");
        sourceList.Add("2");
        sourceList.Add("3");
        sourceList.Add("4");
        sourceList.Add("5");
        MyListView.ItemsSource = sourceList;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var stringItem in sourceList) 
        {
            // get every listview item first
            ListViewItem item  = MyListView.ContainerFromItem(stringItem) as ListViewItem;
            // the DependencyObject is the Grid that you want to get
            DependencyObject grid = FindChild(item);
        }
    }

    // a recursive function to find DependencyObjects that are grid
    public DependencyObject FindChild(DependencyObject parant) 
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
            if (MyChild is Grid)
            {
                // My datatemplate is simple, so I could just get the TextBlock. 
                //If you are using a different datatemplate, you will need to modify the following code to do want you want.
                Grid myGrid = (Grid)MyChild;
                TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)myGrid.Children.FirstOrDefault();

                textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                return myGrid;
            }
            else
            {
                var FindResult = FindChild(MyChild);
                return FindResult;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I've already tried getting ListViewItem by ContainerFromItem() before. But always I'm getting null. I had something like foreach loop with ListView.Items and then called ListView.ContainerFromItem(item). Any ideas why?

Comment: @ValentinMaschenko Please share the code snippet that could reproduce this issue. You could update your original question.

Comment: @ValentinMaschenko I can't tell what causes that behavior just with the ListView code

Comment: Check please :)

Comment: @ValentinMaschenko Well, the code you shared is still not complete enough to reproduce this issue.  But I have a guess. You should pass the **data** which corresponding to the ListViewItem as parameter when you call `ContainerFromItem()`. The parameter of `ContainerFromItem()` is not the ListViewItems. But in your code, you are passing a listviewitem as parameter. You should use the source list which you bind to the `ListView.ItemsSource` like the `sourceList` in my code.  As you could see my code, I'm using items from the `sourceList` when calling `ContainerFromItem()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats seems to be working. If something will be wrong I contact you here. :)